# O que devo fazer para exibir o o retorno do get da classe em PHP?

Tags: php

tenho o seguinte código em PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

include '../model/class/classUser.php';
    $UserNow = new User();
    $UserNow->setName(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $UserNow->setUsername(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
    $UserNow->setYourOcupation(htmlspecialchars($_POST['yourOcupation']));
    $UserNow->setYourGraduation(htmlspecialchars($_POST['yourGraduation']));
    $UserNow->setEmail(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
    $UserNow->setPassword(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));
    $RPassword=htmlspecialchars($_POST['rPassword']);

   $x=$UserNow->getName();

    echo  "
    $UserNow->getName();
 ";
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

O código **não funciona** e o navegador avisa que está indefinida a função getName.
Mas quando eu faço isso:

```
<?
...
 $x=$UserNow->getName();

    echo  "
    $x

     ";
  ?>
```

então ele **funciona**.
Mas eu não quero ter que criar variaveis temporarias toda vez que usar uma classe.O que devo fazer para exibir o o retorno do get da classe?

Comment: tire as aspas do seu echo. Por exemplo echo $userNow->getName();

Comment: Sergio, percebi que suas perguntas não têm respostas aceitas. Pra te avisar: você pode escolher uma resposta (apenas uma) como correta para cada pergunta que fizer, isso é feito através do **✓** no lado esquerdo da resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remova as aspas dentro do seu echo

**edit:**

Ou

```
$x=$UserNow->getName();

echo $x;
```

Comment: ual! Muito obrigado :D

Comment: por nada, se puder votar na resposta e marcar como correta, agradeço